# Message pickup takes a pause with replicated Level db + Zookeeper

Tags: activemq-classic, apache-zookeeper

I've configured 3 ActiveMQ instances along with Zookeeper (Using multi replicated level db). 
For verifying if it works fine with zookeeper or not, I've one producer and 8 consumers. Producer has produced around 1000 messages and I am shutting the producer. 
Now these threads pick from the queue and keep on processing. I am using consumer.receive() method in the code it blocks for sometime ( indefinite time ) and restarts processing. I see the threads, all are waiting for the messages to be picked from the queue. I am not sure, why this happens even though we have enough messages to be consumed on the queue.
Can anyone please help ?
Regards,
JE

Note :
ActiveMQ version :5.10
ZooKeeper Version : 3.4.6